# Bitwise operations on unsigned long long in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, unsigned-long-long-int

I've stumbled upon a following problem, could anyone please help?
I'm trying to use bitwise operations, and I'm expecting this to print the value of 2^50. The output, however, is 0. The maximum I can get it to print is 2^31, which is supposed to be the maximum of normal int, right? So am I doing something terribly wrong here? Thanks in advance.

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<inttypes.h> 
> int main(void)  
> {
> uint64_t x=(1<<50);
> printf("%"PRIu64,x);
> return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: That 1 is not a `uint64_t` yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make your constant an unsigned long long type, which guarantees at least 64 bits in size:

```
uint64_t x=(1LLU<<50);
```